# Servlet filter "returning" an object for later use

Tags: java, servlets

I'm implementing security in my RESTful webservice, and I'm thinking of creating a filter that checks if the Authorization header is valid or not, and this check is done by sending the token to a third party endpoint. If the token is valid, the third party endpoint has to send me a response that contains information regarding the token's expiration, client id, scope, and other stuff. The logic, then, is this:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(
        final ServletRequest request, 
        final ServletResponse response,
        final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    header = req.getHeader("Authorization");
    EndpointResponse eResponse = Endpoint.validate(header);
    if(eResponse.valid())){
      chain.doFilter(...);
      return eResponse; //or equivalent
    }else{
      HttpServletResponse res = HttpServletResponse(response);
      res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
      ...
    }
}
```

Then, in a DAO class, I will use the eResponse like this

```
public final class DAO{    
    public void checks(){
        if(eResponse.scope() == "ADMIN"){
            ...
        }else{
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to inject or return an object after the filter does the validation? Hopefully, without using spring or hibernate, since I can't use these at my job.

-EDIT-

The way I'm accessing the DAO would be like this

```
@Path("")
public class CertificationService {

    @GET
    @Produces(CertificationApplication.SUPPORTED_REPRESENTATIONS)
    @Path(CertificationConstants.URL_PATH)
    public Response getCertificationByUpId(String upId) throws CertificationException {        
        ResponseBuilder response;    
        try{
            response = Response.ok(DAO.findCertificationByUPID(upId));
        } catch (CertificationException e) {
            response = handleException(e);
        }
        return response.build();
    }


 }
```

The findCertificationByUPID method would have to call the checks() method I declared above.

Comment: @JigarJoshi OP question is not at all about an error using string compare. He's asking if his logic is good and how he should do it.

Comment: you can pass it as argument to DAO, from where you call it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the object on the request using `setAttribute()`:

```
request.setAttribute("auth", eResponse);
```

Then your controller can grab the object using

```
EndpointResponse eResponse = (EndpointResponse) request.getAttribute("auth");
```

and do whatever you like with it (including passing it to the DAO):

```
dao.checks(eResponse);
```

where `DAO` is like what you have above, but with

```
public void checks(EndpointResponse eResponse) { ... }
```

instead.

If you prefer to keep the EndpointResponse out of the DAO, you can do

```
public void checks(String role) { ... }
```

or similar.

Comment: Should the eResponse object be static? Or how will the DAO be able to access the same object as the one used in the filter?

Comment: Your DAO should not be tied to the ServletRequest at all, this is a bad practice.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Agreed, but I considered that out of scope of his immediate question. Just going along with the design he presented.

Comment: Updated to reflect Luiggi's comment.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would tying the ServletRequest to the DAO be a bad thing?

Comment: The DAO is conceptually more fundamental than the UI technology. You should be able to use the DAO without regard to the UI. Passing the EndpointResponse into the DAO makes this impossible.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using JEE5. Will I still be able to use @Context to get the request from the resource class?

Comment: Not sure which resource class you have in mind, but both the filter and the servlet see the request (doFilter(), doGet(), doPost(), service(), etc.).